# Terminal of unix can be without square brackets

Tags: unix, terminal

Can i make look  like root@arch$.
Instead if [root@arch~],
I don't like square braces.
Help me if you know i want to remove square[] bracess.

Comment: Check this link for how to change your command prompt. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie

Answer (score 0):

The prompt you're talking about is named `PS1`, and you can customise its appearance in your .bashrc file.

So edit that file and add something like the following:

`PS1="\\u@\\h:\\w"`

The next time you log in you should have your new appearance.

Comment: Thanks But can i add color to root text over there?

Comment: Absolutely.  You're best just Googling something like 'linux PS1 prompt', there's loads about it

Answer (score 0):

```
PS1="\[\e[1;31m\]\u\[\e[0;15m\]@\\h \\w "
```

Insert the above code in '~/.bashrc' file, whenever you open a terminal '~/.bashrc' file will be executed hence you get custom prompt.
Tinker with numbers above to get desired colors.